# Apparent Contradiction in Bloch's Theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals

As far as I learned, there are two ways to state the Bloch's theorem. One is that the translation of a Bloch function is proportional to a complex phase,

$$ \psi(\mathbf{r} + \mathbf{R}) = e^{i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{R}} \psi(\mathbf{r}), $$

and the other is that a Bloch function is composed of a function with the symmetry of the lattice, $ u(\mathbf{r} + \mathbf{R}) = u(\mathbf{r}) $, enveloped by a plane-wave,

$$ \psi(\mathbf{r}) = e^{i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} u(\mathbf{r}). $$

However, expanding in a Fourier series the first equation, where

$$ \mathbf{k} = \sum_i x_i \mathbf{b}_i $$

and $ x_i = \mathbb{Z}/N_i $, with $ N_i $ being the number of crystals in $ i $ direction, we have

$$ \sum_{\mathbf{k}'} \psi_{\mathbf{k}'} e^{i\mathbf{k}' \cdot ( \mathbf{r} + \mathbf{R})} = e^{i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{R}}  \sum_{\mathbf{k}'} \psi_{\mathbf{k}'} e^{i\mathbf{k}' \cdot \mathbf{r}}. $$

Contracting it with $ e^{- i\mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{r}} $ and integrating in $ \mathbf{r} $, $ \int d^3 \mathbf{r} $, both sides we find

$$ \psi_\mathbf{q} \left(e^{i\mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{R}} - e^{i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{R}} \right) = 0 $$

that means that either $ \psi_\mathbf{q} = 0 $ or $ e^{i\mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{R}} = e^{i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{R}} $.

Doesn't this imply that a Bloch function is actually

$$ \psi(\mathbf{r}) = e^{i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} \psi_\mathbf{k}, $$

where $ \psi_\mathbf{k} $ does not depend on the position, in contradiction with the second statement of the Bloch function? Please, if you know, tell me what I did wrong here.

Comment: The most sense I can make of it is that the Fourier coefficients are null for every $ \mathbf{k}' \neq \mathbf{k} + \mathbf{G} $. That way we can put in evidence $ e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{R}} $ in the 4th equation and inside the sum the terms are all of the form $ \psi_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}} $.

Comment: Your comment is the answer.